# Printf / show values on MPLAB X IDE - dsPIC33F

Tags: printf, can-bus, mplab, dspic

I'm a real PIC beginner and I'm trying to use a development board with a dsPIC33F, using the MPLAB X IDE and CANalyzer. I send CAN frames with the dsPIC but the data read by CANalyzer is not the one I tried to send. Is ther any way I can check my variables values or my frames on MPLAB IDE ?

I tried to use printf following the instructions on forums but it seems can't open an UART window :/

I send a frame with a DLC = 0x001 and a data = 0x002, the ID and DLC read by CANanalyzer are correct but it says that the data received is "00".

RESOLVED (Frames init problem)

Comment: Use the debugger with MPLABx e.g. the ICD4

Comment: You can't do any form of programming without a debugger.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was my frames initializations